# how to write a client code in Golang to call createSnapshot softlayer API

Tags: go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Being new to Golang (in fact started learning it just a couple of days back) I have a very basic question on creating a client code for consuming the SL APIs.

So my requirement is to call a createsnapshot SL API using Golang which will take snapshot of my endurance volume, provided that volume id is a input parameter to it. Can you please help me with a sample code for writing this client ?

I know how to do it in python, here is how I did it python, but now I want it in golang (change in req. you know ;) )

python code snippet:

```
    client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env("softlayer username", "softlayer apikey")
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].createSnapshot("snapshot_name", "volume id")
```

thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If i am not misunderstanding, you are using Softlayer package for python to do what you are doing in your given code.

Softlayer has official go package as well [here](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go)

Download the package in your go environment by

> go get github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/...

Then import he package in your application and use it.

basic Example:

```
// 1. Create a session
sess := session.New(username, apikey)

// 2. Get a service
accountService := services.GetAccountService(sess)

// 3. Invoke a method:
account, err := accountService.GetObject()
```

You need to find methods that does the job for you.

Comment: yes, your understanding is correct, I used Python SL package for my earlier development.

And about using the official go package, yes I did read about it but I am having hard time to identify the service/method name for create snapshot and also for datatypes which needs to be provided as input to create snapshot method/service

btw, thank you Mayank for your inputs so far!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script please:

```
// Create Snapshot
//
// This script creates a snapshot for storage
//
// See below references for more details.
// important manual pages:
// http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/createSnapshot
// @License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
// @Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
  username    := "set me"
  apikey      := "set me"

  storageId   := 21015123
  notes       := "test"

  // 1. Create a session
  sess := session.New(username, apikey)

  // 2. Get a service
  service := services.GetNetworkStorageService(sess)

  result, err := service.Id(storageId).CreateSnapshot(&notes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
        return
    } 

  res, errMarsh := json.Marshal(result)
  if errMarsh != nil {
    fmt.Println(errMarsh)
    return
  }

  fmt.Println(string(res))

}
```

**Replace:**: username, apikey, storageId and notes with your own information.

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::createSnapshot](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/createSnapshot)

Comment: thank you ! that helps. One more question, do we need to terminate the session once we are done with it ? Or will the underlying SL GO SDK will take care of its termination ?

Comment: As soon as the script finish, the session will finish with it